# Moving marker in a Google Map on Android

Tags: google-maps, android

I am trying to create something similar to
http://dev.syskall.com/map/

in my android phone application. Basically I have a List of GeoPoints and I need to make the car/marker move on the map according to the values of the geopoints. Putting the mapView code in a loop does not help at all! The map is invalidated till it reaches the last location in the list and then shows up with the latest location only so I can't see any movement of the marker.

If anyone has created this on Android, can you get back to me?

Answer (score 1):

You should add marker to current point and remove from previous one manually. Likewise , you can create moving icon like car moving. 
Try with this :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312754/move-marker-on-google-maps-api-2